# TikZ: using the pos = x in a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

Why doesn't the `pos = x` option work when the node is used in the `plot` command?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw plot[domain = 0:2, samples = 100] ({\x}, {(\x)^2}) node[pos = 1.1] 
  {\(y = x^2\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In this picture, `f_{quad}` is my node that should be at `pos = 1.1`.

[image]

Additionally, it doesn't matter what I make `pos` equal to.  It is always at the origin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My feeling is that the `plot` operation is special and the way in which TikZ process it differs with respect to how *canonical* paths are processed. Quoting the manual:

> The plot path operation can be used to append a line or curve to the path that goes through a large number
>   of coordinates.

This suggests that the whole plot is appended to the path and thus that could be a possible reason why `nodes` can be appended only at the beginning or at the end of a `plot` path.

However, it is always possible to exploit the `decorations.markings` library as a workaround.

An example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,png,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{insert node/.style args={#1 at #2}{
    postaction=decorate,
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark= at position #2
        with
        {
         #1
        }
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[insert node={\node[red,left]{\(y = x^2\)};} at 0.65,
  insert node={\node[blue,draw,right]{\(y = x^2\)};} at 0.45,
  insert node={\node[green!80!black,above]{\(y = x^2\)};} at 1,
  ] plot[domain = 0:2, samples = 100] ({\x}, {(\x)^2});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  At the present, I will use it, but I plan on waiting a few days to see if anyone has a fix.  If not, I will surely accept.

Comment: @dustin: you're welcome. :)

Answer (score 6):

Regardless of whether you use the `pos` key, a node will not be placed along a subpath unless an internal "timer" command as been specified, which determines how a node will be positioned along the last subpath (e.g., a line or a curve). Path construction commands specify the appropriate timer and also set other parameters which the timer requires.

In the case of plots, a timer is not specified and it is difficult to see how they could be given that most plots are essentially made up of lots of very very short lineto subpaths. Even if the parameters were set the last subpath would be a very very short straight line (depending on the number of samples) meaning any `pos` value would place the node at (or very near) the end of the plot.

Furthermore, if you set the `pos` key when a timer has not been specified  (which is the case at the end of a plot) then the node is not moved to any position (even if you use `at`) and is dumped at the origin (I'm not saying this is desirable, this is just what happens currently). If you remove the `pos` key the node is placed centered (depending on the anchor) on the last point of the plot.

As has been pointed out, the markings decoration can be used, however, as the manual states, as decorations use TeX for maths it isn't guaranteed to be very accurate with paths made up of lots of very short subpaths.