# Labelling tikz nodes AND edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels

The following is a snippet of the original.  It works..,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} % drawing support
\usetikzlibrary{trees,arrows,decorations.markings}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,.5,0}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1,scale=1,label/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={ markings, mark=at position .5 with \node #1;}} }]
    \node at (0,0) (node0) [inner sep=0pt,minimum width=1mm,circle,draw=blue] {1};                       % node#1 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The label style is primarily for edges which don't appear in the snippet above.  However, I'd like to label the nodes, too:  change the \node line to:

```
\node at (0,0) (node0) [inner sep=0pt,minimum width=1mm,circle,draw=blue] [label=60:X] {1};                       % node#1
```

which is intended to put the letter "X" at a 60 degree angle from the node.

Tikz then "blesses" me with a

```
Package tikz Error: A node must have a (possibly empty) label text.
```

I've tried numerous combinations of [] {} etc, and haven't gotten the code to work.

Comment: I think to call `label` a custom style is bad as there's already a `label`: check on the manual. A more correct way (_at least it works ;)_ ) to do that (I mean using the library markings) is my style [insert node](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128584/13304).

Comment: \tikzstyle{edgelabel}=[style={postaction={decorate,decoration={ markings, mark=at position .5 with \node #1;}} }]

Comment: Don't use the obsolete `tikzstyle`, see [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/13304)

Answer (score 1):

As TikZ already has already a `label` option (see section **16.10 The Label and Pin Options** in the pgfmanual) you can not define your own style calling it `label` (moreover with a different aim).